# Getting though firewall without VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, nat, android

I am trying to control geographically remote (Android) machines using VNC.  Some of these machines are behind firewalls.  I was planning on putting all these machines on a VPN and being done with it.  Then I could log into the VPN and be able to control the machines.

However, to use a VPN with Android is problematic, because on reboot, Android requires the user to [manually approve](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) the VPN.

`User action is required to create a VPN connection.`

The main thing I need to is be able to access each Android with VPN though a firewall.  Is there another way to be able to do this without a VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Although there are means to do an awful lot of things even through a firewall (look at the contemporary backdoor software for a colorful list of examples), you would not be able to do any of it on an out-of-the-box Android host as all of this would require appropriate software support at the Android end - which is just the same kind of problem that you have with establishing a VPN connection.

That being said, you might take a look at what [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/index.html) can do for you. The small [VPNCilla project](https://sites.google.com/site/mjm4456/vpncilla/vpncilla-automation) is an example of how VPNC (a Cisco VPN client) can be auto-run by Tasker. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tasker/5im21LkhjDc) you will find a short discussion thread where people claim to have other VPN clients autostarted via Tasker - including OpenVPN.